# TabActivity Implementing

Tags: android, tabactivity

I am trying to make a tab activity. It works fine . I make 
`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` in the definition in manifest file. But sometimes it does not take the full screen when launching. My program starts from a splash screen. That is an normal activity. My tab is at the buttom of the screen. So the tabs are go inside the screen.

Does Anyone know about the problem?

Comment: it is happening when i pressed the home button. But my problem is i cannot remove the view or finish the activity when on pressing the home button or in on pause/ on resume state. i need this home should enabled.

Comment: hii all i solved the problem.....actually the thing is.. the page goes like this--->  splash screen-> home-> from home i opened a page.. then this page is on resume... so i cannot call finish... so i just add a flag and in my onpause() i set the value of that flag and check this when on onresume()  is called... if it cames from next activity, then I does not do anything and when it came from splash screen then if home button pressed, then i just see the value of the flag...and call appropriate action......

Answer (score 1):

Remove **.FullScreen** and instead use

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

with your activity tags in AndroidManifest.XML, worked out for me

**EDIT**

in your Activity **onCreate** method use

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: I need full screen as the requirement.So this solution is not working

Comment: if you not giving .full screen then how you implement the full screen with no title bar?